# How file managers app access shared files data

Tags: android, file, file-management

I'm trying to implement something close to a File Manager.
I'm trying to browse files in the "Internal Shared Storage".
But when I try to list folder content using `listFiles();` I always get null.

Just to make sure I tried this code:

```
try {
    otherPkg = getPackageManager().
    getPackageInfo("com.other.pkg", 0).
    applicationInfo.dataDir;
} catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
File dataDir = new File(otherPkg );
File[] files = dataDir.listFiles();
```

`dataDir`  gets populated properly so the package is located,
but `files` is always null.

Maybe I need permission added to my manifest?
Or I'm just doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I think I understood what is the problem.
The package manager returns the path to the internal memory where I don't have permission to read/write data.

First I needed to add these permissions to the manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Then I needed to call:

String dirPath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath();
File[] files = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().listFiles();

That I think I can search from here the specific directory that I need.